# Change top level menu item to point to custom submenu item

Tags: admin, wp-admin, admin-menu, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I'm using a plugin called CMS Page Order http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-page-order/ (Now referred to as CPO)

It's pretty simple, the said plugin adds a new item to the submenu of every custom post type. The menu item leads to a page where you can reorder the posts of the certain post type.

I've added so that you can create new posts directly from this view, so basically it's like the default edit post view in Wordpress, but you can reorder your posts aswell. This renders the usual post edit page pretty useless.

**So my question is**, is there a way for me to remove the "All *post type*'s" submenu item (`edit.php?post_type=nameofposttype`) replacing it with this menu item created by CPO while also making the top level menu item itself point to the page created by CPO.

–––

What I've been trying to do is to try to replace the top level menu item with the URL of the submenu item created by CPO using the plugin Admin Menu Editor, but changing the URL via the plugin is not allowed it seems. I then tried moving the CPO menu item to the top of the submenu as I noticed that the top level menu item points to the topmost submenu item (ie "All pages/posts"). That did not work either, as it produces an URL that is erroneous (it makes the top level menu item point to `admin.php?page=order-xxx`)

Here's some images to further explain what I mean.
[image: Here's how the top level item regurlarly behaves]

Here's how the top level item behaves as default (`edit.php?post_type=xxx`)

[image: Now here's what happens if I move my page with the special menu handler to the top. The top level item gets a new URL, but it's erroneous]

Now here's what happens if I move my page with the special menu handler to the top. The top level item gets a new URL, but it's erroneous (`admin.php?page=order-xxx`)

[image: Here's the url that the special menu handler page has, the URL that the top level menu item should have]

Here's the URL that the special menu handler page has, the URL that the top level menu item *should* have (`edit.php?post_type=xxx&page=order-xxx`)

So, how can I change the top level menu item to the URL I want?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I simply don't understand a) What's wrong b) What you're trying to get.

Comment: @kaiser I elaborated now, still feels kind of fuzzy to me aswell. I'm not sure I've got the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also change the menu with the global variables of WordPress for display the menu and submenu.
All first items are in the var `$menu` and all suparts are in `$submenu`.

Also a small example for change the order of the submenu-items with `edit.php`.
Add thius plugin and see the result via debugging. The function `fb_cmp` is only the logic for reorder, but you can define you custom order in this function, she is the callback for [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: .my Tests
 * Plugin URI:  http://bueltge.de/
 * Description: 
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_get_menu' );
function fb_get_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    var_dump( $submenu['edit.php'] );
    usort( $submenu['edit.php'], 'fb_cmp' );
    echo '<hr>';
    var_dump( $submenu['edit.php'] );
}

function fb_cmp( $a, $b ) {

    if ($a->value == $b->value)
        return 0;
    else
        return $a->value < $b->value ? 1 : -1; // reverse order
}
```

As hint the result in a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

have you tried considering jquery? Maybe this will help you. Ive tried it and it worked. Just put this in your functions.php

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'change_post_url');
function change_post_url(){
?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){         
        $(".anchor_class_name").attr("href","sample.php");
    });
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: That might be a way if there's no other way to do it. I tend to try to rely on jQuery as little as possible in situations like this.

Comment: yah I just also use it when theres no more options left but sometimes in order to save time jQuery is a way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can simply use `add_query_arg( 'key', 'value' );` when registering the page.

I explained the details of the WordPress admin menu system [in this blog article](http://unserkaiser.com/code/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/). Can't post this hear as it's much too much and mucho too much.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I can use this to make clicking "Livsmedel" behave like you just clicked "New Sortable Menu". I just want to replace the regular view where pages and posts are listed, with my custom page and have it behave like it would do normally with the submenu getting highlighted when top level menu item is clicked/active.

Comment: @INT See update and link.